# when i import child class in parent class pyqt5 to run automatically second class window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

in this code direct run second window, but i want when i click on button in first window then show second window

first window class file

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
from PyQt5.QtGui import*
from PyQt5.QtCore import*
from secondwindow import secondwindow
class firstwindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        QTimer.singleShot(10000,self.newwindow)
        '''super(firstwindow,self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("First Window")

        self.button = QPushButton("ClickMe")
        widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.newwindow)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)'''
    def newwindow(self):
        self.newpage = secondwindow(self)

        self.newpage.show()

class main():
    app = QApplication([])
    window = firstwindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

second window class file

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
from PyQt5.QtGui import*
from PyQt5.QtCore import*

class secondwindow(QMainWindow):
    def setupUI(self):
        super(secondwindow,self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Second Window")
        self.show()

class main():
    app = QApplication([])
    window = secondwindow()
    window.setupUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I aslo try this code but not show my first window directly show second window

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it counts as solution, I believe both windows are there from the beginning, but second one is hidden untill pressing the button (aka no child parent relation, both MainWindows as in the example I think):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Jun  8 13:22:25 2020

@author: Pietro
"""

import sys 
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from secondwindow import secondwindow 

class firstwindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self): 
        super(firstwindow,self).__init__() 
        self.setWindowTitle("First Window")
        self.resize(800, 200)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("ClickMe",self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.newwindow)
        self.newpage = secondwindow()

    def newwindow(self):
        self.newpage.show()





class main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = firstwindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

secondwindow.py :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Jun  8 13:25:20 2020

@author: Pietro
"""
import sys 
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets 

class secondwindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(secondwindow,self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Second Window")
        self.hide()
```

Comment: i want class files are different first window class file and second window class file